# Connect to SQL database for Silverlight app

Tags: database, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Can you connect your app to a SQL database? Silverlight - which Windows Phone apps are built on - only seems to like XML.

Then, how do you show the data in the app and how do you fall back if you cannot access the internet or the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango) is able to support a smaller version of SQL. [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) will bring you to the Local Database Overview for Windows Phone MSDN documentation.

After reading the overview, look in the left pane and notice the other resources for setting up and using local SQL data in a phone app.